# Выборка из бд, фильтр одинаковых значений

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Всем привет, нужна помощь!
Усть 2 столбца es и name, нужно чтобы показывало все строки где есть es = 2, и убирались повторяющиеся строки, если в поле name одинаковое значение.

Заранее спасибо

$resultat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `invlist` WHERE `es` = '2';",$db);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно поможет группировка по полю name

```
SELECT * FROM invlist WHERE es = '2' GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: спасибо, большое